# Unable to call servlet from javascript

Tags: servlets

I am calling the servlet using this code:

```
document.location.href= '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/dropdown';
```

While the function is called using `onload`

When the page gets loaded, I am getting the following HTTP 404 error:

```
$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D
```

Comment: This won't work (the EL syntax ${}) unless it's in a JSP.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal - It is in a JSP file only

Comment: Remove onload and check the path being generated.

Comment: The path works perfectly. When I load it using onload i get this as my error `menu/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/dropdown`

Comment: I meant check the source html for the path being generated (view > source). I think the EL is not being processed. If yes, post your JSP.

Comment: EL is working but my foreach is not iterating
Code - 
`<c:forEach var="i" items="${myList}">
<c:out value="test"/>  
<option><c:out value="${i}"/> </option></c:forEach>`